# Datagrid Displaymemberpath

Tags: sql, wpf, datagrid, combobox

i have a datagrid with a comboboxcolumn which works fine, but is it possible to get 2 Displaymembers? I want to show fore- and lastname in the box, but i just get one of them...

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="226" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataSet}, Path=PlacementsEmployees}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="739,57,0,0" Name="mitGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" DataContext="{Binding}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" IsReadOnly="True" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="11">
    <WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        <WpfToolkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="test" Header="Employees" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataSet}, Path=Employees}" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=PE_Employees}" DisplayMemberPath="E_Surname" -> maybe "E_Forename; E_Surname" ?? <- IsReadOnly="True" />
    </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
</WpfToolkit:DataGrid>
```

the reason why i want to use just one column is, that i just want one header (in my case: employees)
u guys see my problem? Maybe there is a possibility with a datatemplate :)

Comment: What shows up in the drop down now?

Comment: nothing, its just for presenting, not for editing. readonly = true :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you bind to two different objects PlacementEmployees and Employees?

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayMemberPath` property allows you not to create custom `DataTemplate` in case of displaying only one property of a bound class. If you want something more than displaying one property you should create your own `DataTemplate`.

Comment: yeah and there's the problem, would you help me out?